# Customize Formtastic to automatically add the class "required" to elements that are required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

How would I go about having Formtastic automatically add the class "required" to elements that are required by rails validation?

I see that you can create custom inputs by adding the specified inputs in app/inputs but I don't see a way to check to see if it's required.

I'm assuming it would be something like:

```
class StringInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput 
  include Base::Stringish
  include Base::Validations
  def input_html_options
    if required?
      super.merge(:class => "required")
    end
  end
end
```

but it's not working :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it does this anyway if you just ask it to:

```
<%= form.input :tutor_id, as: :select, collection: @student.tutors.all(order: 'name'), required: true %>
```

(this is Ruby 1.9 syntax)

Comment: nah, this is the output for a string with required set: <input id="user_dependents_first_name" name="user[dependents][first_name]" type="text">

Comment: Try putting the field inside a form.inputs block - I think I had the same problem.

Comment: It is :/ It does however add the required class to the list element, just not the input (which I kinda want for automatic jquery validate)

Comment: It outputs <li class="string required" id="company_name_input">... so I would change your CSS selectors to care about `li.required input`

Comment: @JesseWolgamott yea, that's what I'm going to have to do. I was hoping to add a slew of other customizations based on other validations but I'm thinking it's probably more trouble than it's worth. Thanks guys.

Comment: You could, of course, not use Formtastic and roll a helper that looks at the validations?

Comment: @Ghoti I figured since formtastic already had the concept of what is required and other validations that this would be trivial. It very well might be but I didn't want to burn time with it. I'll manage them in two places for now and pay my developer debt later.

Comment: Why not ask the formtastic maintainer on the site? He gets back pretty quick and is a very nice guy. :)